# Uncaught ReferenceError: openDatabase is not defined

Tags: javascript, web-sql, google-chrome-app

I am trying to use `openDatabase` with a Google Chrome app but the following error is displayed:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: openDatabase is not defined

I also added permissions (`unlimitedStorage`) in manifest.json.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebSQL is disabled for Chrome apps, as you can see in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated.html).

If you want to save data persistently, use the [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) API, [`IndexedDB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB) or the [`chrome.fileSystem`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage.html) API (not to be confused with the [HTML5 Filesystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/File_API/File_System_API)!).

Answer (score 0):

dexie js work prefect in chrome apps